# Why is the fundamental matrix defined up to a scale

Tags: math, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Why is the fundamental matrix defined up to a scale?

I know the fundamental matrix can become from the essential matrix, and it is up to scale, but I do not know why either.

Explain why the fundamental matrix defined up to a scale, and what is meaning for the up to a scale in this situation. Thank you.

Comment: This question is not related to programming. Please see [help/on-topic] to learn what you can ask about here.

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental matrix is defined by the equation `x'^t F * x = 0`. But once we have an `F` that solves this equation for given set of pixels `(x', x)`, we can always multiply `F` by any scalar `a` and still solve the equation `x'^t * a*F * x = 0`, since we can factor `a` and eliminate it with the 0 on the other side. Thus, `F'=a*F` is also a valid fundamental matrix.

Instead of saying that there is an infinite number of such matrices, or that there is a one-parameter family of matrices, we simply say that there is a unique fundamental matrix, up to a scale. In other words, it is just another way of saying that there are many solutions, but that we know how to easily get these other solutions once we have one of them.